# Can't show "delete" for logged user by use !current_user?(user)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

_user.html.erb

```
<li>
  <%= gravatar_for user, size: 50 %>
  <%= link_to user.name, user %>
  <% if current_user.admin? && !current_user?(user)%>
    | <%= link_to "delete", user, method: :delete,
                                  data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
  <% end %>
</li>
```

I delete `&& !current_user?(user)` It can work
This is my code
session_helper.er.html

```
def current_user
    if (user_id = session[:user_id])
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
    elsif (user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id])
      user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
      if user && user.authenticated?(cookies[:remember_token])
        log_in user
        @current_user = user
      end
    end
  end
  def current_user?(user)
    user = current_user  
  end
  def logged_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end
  def log_out
    forget(current_user)
    session.delete(:user_id)
    @current_user = nil
  end
```

users_contorller

```
  def index
      @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 10)
  end
  def new
      @user = User.new
  end
  def create
      @user = User.new(user_params)
      if @user.save
          log_in @user
          flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
          redirect_to @user
      else
          render 'new'
      end
  end
  def edit
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
```

/##
      private
      def user_params
          params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
      end
      def logged_in_user
        unless logged_in?
        store_location
        flash[:danger] = "please login"
        redirect_to login_url
        end
      end
     //##
      def correct_user
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        redirect_to(root_path) unless @user == current_user?(@user)
      end
      def admin_user
          redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.admin?
      end

Session_controller.html.erb

```
class SessionController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end
//##
  def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      log_in user
      params[:session][:remember_me] == '1' ? remember(user) : forget(user)
      redirect_back_or user
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = '無效的電子郵件/密碼'
      render 'new'
    end
  end
//##
  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])

  end
//##
  def destroy
        log_out if logged_in?
        redirect_to root_url
  end

end
```

I can't find some error for it and I am a newbie at ruby on rails .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `current_user` method you should use comparison (`==`) instead of assignment (`=`):

```
def current_user?(user)
  user == current_user
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the user login to

```
<% if current_user.admin? && user_login?(user)%>
  | <%= link_to "delete", user, method: :delete,data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
<% end %>
```

and

```
def user_login?(user)
  user == current_user
end
```

Comment: Cool! Thank you so much :) You are life saver